# Regex for atleast 1 special character, 1 number and 1 letter, min length 8 characters C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate the password. I am using Data Annotations in my ViewModels like below:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z[0-9]@$!%*#?&]{8,}$",ErrorMessage="Password must contain atleast 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 special character.")]
```

When I try to register with the right format, it still gives me the error message.

Can someone please look at it and help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to validate content

```
([a-zA-Z]{1,})([@$!%*#?&]{1,})([0-9]{1,})
```

But I would use another data-annotation attribute to validate length. Then you will know if your ModelState is failing because of invalid characters or length, for example `[StringLength]`

Comment: That doesn't work properly... eg `#abc123` will fail because your regex demands that you have a letter before the special character.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex, you have

`[A-Za-z[0-9]@$!%*#?&]`

You don't need the inner square brackets for `[0-9]`. It should be `0-9` or `\d`.